# Use repeated placeholder with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to show placeholder as repeated in imageViews using glide, I am able to do it withoud glide using

```
ImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawablePlaceholder())
```

But When Glide is used like

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();

        requestOptions.placeholder(getDrawablePlaceholder())
                .fitCenter();

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(imageview);

  private BitmapDrawable getDrawablePlaceholder() {

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder_user);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
        bitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        bitmapDrawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        return bitmapDrawable;
    }
```

Background is not repeated, placeholder get displayed in center only.

Comment: remove .fitCenter() and try like "requestOptions.placeholder(getDrawablePlaceholder());"

Comment: have tried but is of no use, thanks for suggestion.